# Iteratively create functions and endpoints for FASTAPI

Tags: python, fastapi, langchain

I am currently working on building an application with multiple FASTAPI endpoints that will allow us to do GridSearch on our LLM application (testing different LLMs, different schema entry into prompt, different ways of passing in example data, etc).

Currently I am manually creating each endpoint for each combination of parameters like so:

```
chain_param1a_param2a = RunnableLambda(func_param1a_param2a)
api_handler_param1a_param2a = APIHandler(chain_param1a_param2a, path="/param1a_param2a")
@app.post("/param1a_param2a/invoke", include_in_schema=False)
async def simple_invoke_param1a_param2a(request: Request) -> Response:
     return await api_handler_param1a_param2a.invoke(request)
    
chain_param1a_param2b = RunnableLambda(func_param1a_param2b)
api_handler_param1a_param2b = APIHandler(chain_param1a_param2b, path="/param1a_param2b")
@app.post("/param1a_param2b/invoke", include_in_schema=False)
async def simple_invoke_param1a_param2b(request: Request) -> Response:
     return await api_handler_param1a_param2b.invoke(request)
```

Is there any way I can iteratively create the chains, api_handlers and async functions so that I don't have to do this manually as we hope to test more combination of parameters?

Comment: Make a dict mapping all model names to the `APIHandler` instances. Then use a path param for the route `@app.post("/{model}/invoke") def invoke(model: str, ...)`. Use the model name from the path to do a lookup on the dict.

Comment: You can call `add_api_route` directly instead of using the decorators to let you to register URLs programmatically: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/a315048357dc6412348fa5a52f62ed46db90bd53/fastapi/routing.py#L843